# Should plot-recurring characters always be Wild Cards?

Tags: savage-worlds, npc

The PCs are demigods and have allies (also demigods) who travel with them constantly. They've become quite important to the PCs' lives though they're not "necessary," plot-wise.

Since the allied Extras are demigods and are also showing up every game session, should I turn them into Wild Cards or leave them as they are?

Comment: My answer for this question would essentially be exactly the same as for http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46399/should-savage-world-allies-be-made-as-wild-cards

Comment: Aldath, could you clarify if this question is substantially different to the previous one, and if so how?